# Como calcular o ano a partir do numero de dias?

Tags: algoritmo, data

Sem usar nenhuma biblioteca, e ignorando pequenos fatos científicos sobre a rotação da terra.
A função recebe o número de dias e deve determinar quantos anos se passaram julgando o seguinte :

- Anos múltiplos de 4 possuem 366 dias
- Anos múltiplos de 100 possuem 365 dias
- Anos múltiplos de 400 possuem 366 dias
- O ano inicial é 0 (ou seja, precisa de 366 dias para chegar no ano 1)

Resumidamente : Anos multiplos de 4 que não são multiplos de 100 são bisextos, anos multiplos de 400 sempre são bisextos : `(ano % 4 == 0 && ano % 100 == 0) || (ano % 400 == 0)`

O que eu tentei foi o seguinte :

```
int ano(long dias) {
        long anos = dias / 1461L * 4L;
        long bisextos = dias % 1461L;
        if (bisextos < 366) {
            return (int) (anos);
        } else if (bisextos < 731) {
            return (int) (anos + 1);
        } else if (bisextos < 1096) {
            return (int) (anos + 2);
        } else {
            return (int) (anos + 3);
        }
    }
```

E a operação inversa :

```
    int ano(long anos) {
        long dias = 0L;
        long mod = anos % 4L;
        if (anos > 0) {
            dias += ((anos - mod) * 36525L) / 100L;
            if (mod > 0) {
                dias += 366L + (mod - 1L) * 365L;
            }
        }
        return dias;
    }
```

Está funcionando, mas não consigo implementar as diferenças de 100 e 400

Comment: Agora faz sentido, mas acho que seria bom você tentar deixar explícito na pergunta. Porque mesmo eu tendo lido toda ela, acabei levando pro lado "real" da coisa, pode acontecer com mais gente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int ano = 0

while dias > 0 {

    if ano == bissexto then 
        dias = dias-366
    else 
        dias = dias-365

    ano++
} 

return ano
```

Comment: Podes explicar o código?

Comment: Esse código não faz muito sentido, me desculpe,  mas não entendi como aplica-lo  no problema

Comment: Depois de testar aqui eu entendi, basta por a condição no lugar ali de bisexto ... mas fazer isso  não fica pesado ? digamos num loop de retorno de query (sql) com anos de 2000 pra cima ?

Comment: Fiz no telemóvel e o editir não é muito prático, por isso coloquei o algoritmo e não um código executável.

Comment: É para ser desenvolvido em SQL?